# Add custom labels to http_server_requests_seconds_bucket metric in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I'm currently working on a Spring boot (Spring webflux) project where we have exposed metrics of our application on **/actuator/prometheus** endpoint. We have added spring boot actuator dependency which by default gave us the **http_server_requests_seconds_bucket** metric. By default it has **{exception="None",method="POST",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/test",le="0.268435456",}** labels. I want to add another label say "challenge" which depends on the request payload. For example, my request payload looks like this,

```
{
 "type" : "basic",
 "method" : "someMethod"
}
```

I want to add a label within that metric as, `http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{exception="None",method="POST",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/pos/authenticate",le="0.268435456",     challenge="basic"}` which is based on the request payload "type" parameter. Can someone please help with this

**Note:** We only allow limited number of values for "type"

Answer (score 0):

If you borrow from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64913252/3033916) about adding custom tags to existing prometheus actuator metrics and parse the request (I'm using a jackson object mapper) for the property you're interested in, it should do the trick. Would look something like the following:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcTagsContributor webMvcTagsContributor() {

    return new WebMvcTagsContributor() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<Tag> getTags(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler,
            Throwable exception
        ) {

            // parse the request body to get the property we're interested in later
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            ThingToMapFromRequestBody bodyAsObject = null;
            try {
                bodyAsObject = mapper.readValue(request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining()),
                    ThingToMapFromRequestBody.class
                );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // add the property we're interested in to our metrics
            return Tag.of("challenge", bodyAsObject != null ? bodyAsObject.type() : "");
        }

        @Override
        public Iterable<Tag> getLongRequestTags(HttpServletRequest request, Object handler) {

            return null;
        }
    };
}

// making use of a record rather than class, introduced in Java 14
record ThingToMapFromRequestBody(String type, String method) { }
```